# Lost android keystore file

Tags: android, google-play

I lost my Keystore file of an old app, it was deleted by google.
I made a change in the code and I wanted to update my app in google play console. 
is there any way to update an app if we lost the Keystore file?

Comment: You can try with the new app version.

Comment: Not possible to update app without keystore file.You need to upload new app with new package name.

Comment: Did you enable app signing enable in your play console account?? If yes, then you can.

Comment: I enabled app signing but I got always the following error :  Import failed

You have imported an APK that is not signed with the import certificate. You must use the same certificate. The import certificate bears the following digital imprint: